# vb.net 2008 threading passing parameter

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

How do i pass the parameter using threading?

I have a global declaration within a form

```
Dim myRPT As New Reportlist
```

this is the Private sub thread code calling homework sub routines

```
Me.mythread = New Thread(New ThreadStart(AddressOf Me.homework))
            Me.mythread.Start()
```

and this is the content inside the sub routines

```
CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = myRPT
        CrystalReportViewer1.Refresh()
```

thank you in advance.

Comment: Have a look at the MSDN example for passing `Object`'s to parameterized thread delegate: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.parameterizedthreadstart%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2 .. TL;DR: make sure your 'homework' function signature is `Sub homework(ByVal data As Object)` then pass the object in your thread start function: `Me.mythread.start(myRPT)`

Comment: Im having this error..im using vb.net 2008 .net 2.0

Error 3 Method 'Private Sub homework(data As Object)' does not have a signature compatible with delegate 'Delegate Sub ThreadStart()'.

Comment: They don't do new threadstart within the thread in the example

Comment: Read this: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?551803-Passing-Data-to-a-Thread-Entry-Method. The third code example in the first post is directly relevant to you but you should read the whole thing.